# Matching a zero with String::Substitution

Tags: perl

I am trying to match a digit with [`String::Substitution`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution); it works fine if the digit is not zero. If the digit is zero it substitutes the empty string instead of the digit. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use String::Substitution;

my @data = qw(0 1);
for (@data) {
    my $str = $_;
    my $regex = qr/(\d)/;
    my $replace = '$1';
    my $result_str = String::Substitution::gsub_copy($str, $regex, $replace);
    my @m = $str =~ /$regex/g;
    dd $result_str;
    dd @m;
}
```

The output is:

```
""
0
1
1
```

expected output would be:

```
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: Something weird is going on. Trying to find out what

Comment: @ikegami I think there is a bug on line #95 in the source code https://metacpan.org/source/RWSTAUNER/String-Substitution-1.001/lib/String/Substitution.pm ..  it should be `map { ($$_) // '' } ( 1 .. $#- )` Note defined or `//` not regular or `||` as in the source..

Comment: yup, that's the problem.

Comment: Backwards compatible: `defined($$_) ? $$_ : ''`

Comment: Are you going to submit a ticket?

Comment: @ikegami Yes I will try to contact the author..

Comment: The docs suggest you can send an email to `bug-string-substitution at rt.cpan.org`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, bug report has been sent..

Comment: Thanks for the report!  A new version has been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid "uninitialized" warnings, version 1.001 of the module attempts to convert undefined placeholders into empty strings. However, it erroneously uses a truth test rather an defined test to determine which values to replace with an empty string.

```
map { ($$_) || '' } ( 1 .. $#- )
```

That code needs to be changed to

```
map { defined($$_) ? $$_ : '' } ( 1 .. $#- )
```

A bug report has been [submitted](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=103918).